# Arch Linux Network disabling itself

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux

I'm running arch on my Laptop. A few days ago the cable network stopped working. In the network settings of gnome it only shows the MAC address and when I set the switch to on it changes back to of a few seconds later. The output of ip looks like this:

```
ip link show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:26:b0:e2:b6:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

# ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:26:b0:e2:b6:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::226:b0ff:fee2:b6d4/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Turning the ip link down and up didn't change anything.
I've already tried resetting the switch it is connected to, but that didn't help either. 
I don't know what I did to break it or how to fix it back and googling it wasn't any help.
Any ideas?

Comment: Anything helpful reported by `dmesg`?

Comment: How many network managers are you running? Try systemctl stop NetworkManager; dhclient eth0; does it work?

Comment: No nothing from dmesg already checked that

Comment: stopping the NetworkManager just succesfully killed my wifi, but the ethernet doen't work

Comment: did you enable dhcpcd for the ethernet controller?

Comment: dhcp gives this:
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd@.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Di 2013-11-26 08:07:15 CET; 2min 13s ago
  Process: 7972 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dhcpcd -q -w %I (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)